# Oracle select statement caching during large insert has erratic performance

Tags: sql, oracle, caching, indexing, transactional

In a mid-tier server that implements an API with granular *store* methods, we map each *store* call to either an *insert* or *update* statement, based on the existence of the entity, and to determine that, we issue a select across 3 tables joining on natural keys. (our 2nd implementation uses a zero-caching architecture in the mid-tier server, for easy parallelism, so we always go back to the DB).

For a given import, we load for example 180,000 entities into one of our *leaf* tables, each entity has a parent foreign-key into a *parent* table (roughly 9,000 entities), and each *parent* row is *owned* by a 3rd *top-level* table with only 200 rows. All 3 tables use a GUID surrogate key (as the primary key), and they have a (project, parent, name) composite natural key (top-level table has no parent column/key).

The parent columns are proper indexed foreign-keys. And the natural keys all have UNIQUE indexes. We are using Oracle 12c, using OCI in C/C++.

The ideal plan for that join *top-parent-leaf* select is to use the NK indexes, since they always yield a single row, but in the past we've seen bad performance when the query planner would choose the less selective FK indexes.

The scalar select normally takes 0.25 milliseconds on average (1/4 ms). All those select statements are cached with bind variables, and we just update the bound values and execute() to get the result. This takes for example 500s to import 240,000 rows across 6 tables when working normally (in schema A). But in a different schema (B), it's taking *forever*, and under the debugger (Release mode) I can see that 1/4 ms query take around 80ms, way more than normal. (180,000 * 80ms is over 4 hours... just for the selects to map NKs to the SK/PK and know if it's an insert or update we need).

So obviously the query planner is using a wrong plan, not the normal highly selective one using the NK indexes.

My question is how do we avoid the terrible plan?

In particular, those select statements (6 of them, all cached) are prepared at the beginning of the import, and at that time the schema could be empty, but have had plenty of rows before, and in any case, the schema will be filled with rows in all cases, sometimes in the millions. So a plan decided on an *empty* schema may be bad for when the schema starts to be quite *full*, no?

The import is transactional, and all part of a single transaction.

Are we supposed to **re**-prepare the cached select statements as more rows are added? Would the plan be any different, i.e. would the stats be any different, given that we are inside a large transaction anyway?

Should use force the use of the NK-indexes (always the best ones) as query-hints, even though Tom Kyte says never to use them?

In general, when doing a mix of inserts/updates with selects in a large transaction that can significantly affects schema statistics, how to we keep the select plans performance to be optimal?

I guess updating stats is a DDL and thus cannot be performed inside that transaction too. Is there a known strategy to not fall into the performance chasm we sometimes fall into? (from 500s / 9min to several hours...)

Thanks for any insight about the above.

Comment: There are a few of tools and methods, please read [Database Performance Tuning Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/outlines.htm#PFGRF707) to learn them, chapters from 15 to 20. Hints are one of the tools, they are usually not recommended, but they are also not banned, you can use them in difficult situations.

Comment: You're side-stepping the main question IMHO, which is plan "stability" **within a transaction**, when said transaction significantly affects the schema stats. You can't `DBMS_STATS.GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS` in the middle of a transaction AFAIK for example.

Comment: Is there a specific set of table stats that would generate good plans for all workloads?  If so, could you generate the representative data and then gather stats and run DBMS_STATS.LOCK_TABLE_STATS on the relevant tables?  Also, are any of your tables global temporary tables?  (If so that may slightly complicate things.)